# Java Spring mvc,post an object you have in one of his columns other objects referenced in a dropdown list

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I need to send the controller an object having one of his columns other objects referenced this in a dropdown list and make reference to it in this way "object.id"

the jsp.

```
<form:select path="id_group_coverage.id_insurance_company" class="form-control">
     <form:options items="${insuranceCompanies}" itemValue=" id_insurance_company" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

The controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addingModel(@ModelAttribute Coverage objParam,BindingResult result,    
@RequestParam String id_group_coveage,@RequestParam String id_insurance_company)
```

what is the correct form to do? 
thank you!

Comment: Just to see if I understand the request... you want to store the selected value from the drop down into a form field called "object.id" and pass this value to the Controller?

Comment: Yes, that is id_group_coverage.id_insurance_company which is a field called an object coverage.

Comment: What about adding a new field to the Command object, create a <form:hidden> field for this, and then use JavaScript to populate this value on what value is selected?

Comment: really ever I retrieve values from the dropdown lists by the value of the path from the dropdown list, but since now I have to access the property of an object does not know how to do.

Comment: So you're just trying to get a property from an object? As long as it has a `get` method, you just do `${object.property}` since it uses Java Reflection.

Comment: I could solve the problem, I solved retrieving the values from the dropdown lists in javascript Ascalonian thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a new field to the Command object, create a  field for this, and then use JavaScript to populate this value on what value is selected?